# Square root of a negative number squared

Tags: square-numbers

√x^2=|x|,
What about √-x^2 ?
If we use the number $5$ as en example,
would this evaluate to √-5^2 = √25 =5
OR do we need to get the imaginary number 'i' involved, resulting in √-5^2 = 5i
I have found many conflicting answers
Any clarification on the topic would be much appreciated

Kind Regards

Comment: I have no idea what you want to know.

Comment: Note that $-5^2\neq 25$ but rather $-25$. But the main thing is that the symbol $\sqrt{}$ is only well-defined to take a single value (in a nice way) when the argument is a non-negative number.

Comment: There is a convention in mathematics that $-5^2$ is $-25$, not $25$. The square is evaluated before the minus. The square root of $-25$ can be defined to be $5i$ or $-5i$.

Comment: Thank you peter, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Amanda, can you add parentheses to make clear which part of the term is squared and which part is rooted? Now it is ambigious.

Comment: Caution, your title does not match the question and your example $\sqrt{-5^2}$ gives $\sqrt{-25}$, not $\sqrt{25}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real numbers, the square root of a negative is not defined.

$$\color{red}{\sqrt{-25}}.$$

In complex numbers, the square root of a negative can indeed be defined as $i$ times the square root of the absolute value.

$$\sqrt{-25}=5i.$$

But you need to understand the concept of [principal branch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch), as $-5i$ could also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: +1 for the link to the principal branch. It is so easy to simply say that $\sqrt{-1}=i$ without mentioning that expanding square roots to complex numbers is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *HUGE* difference between

$$(\sqrt{-5})^2$$

which is not a well defined expression because the square root is a function only defined on the positive real numbers (and *can* be expanded to the whole complex numbers, but it is not trivial and there actually exist multiple expansions of the function, since both $i^2$ and $(-i)^2$ evaluate to $-1$)

and $$\sqrt{(-5)^2}$$

which is equal to $5$ since $\sqrt{25}=5$.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers currently written do not hit on what I believe to be the true source of confusion here.  The ambiguity in the answer lies not with the square root... but rather on the negative sign.

The value $-5^2$ is most commonly interpreted as $-(5^2)$ which simplifies as $-25$.  It is distinctly different than the value $(-5)^2$ which simplifies as $25$.

The result of $\sqrt{(-5)^2}$ is indeed positive $5$.

The result of $\sqrt{-(5^2)}$ is $5i$.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is ±5.

$-5$ is converted to $5i^2$ then squared, resulting to $25i^4$, according to the PEMDAS rule.

The root of $25i^4$ is then evaluated by taking the roots of a complex number. Note that $z = r(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi)$, where $z$ is the $n$-th root.

$r$ is the real root part, but in this case is used to contain imaginary numbers as well. Therefore, $r = \sqrt{25i^4} = 5i^2$, without regard to sign.

$\phi = 360°/n$, where $n$ is the $n$-th root. Thus, $n = 2$, therefore $\phi = 180°$.

Using the argand diagram, there are two cases, $\phi = 0°$ and $\phi = 180°$. Evaluating $z$, we have $z = -5i^2$ ($\phi = 180°$) and $z = 5i^2$ ($\phi = 0°$), giving us $z = ±5$ upon simplification.

The only thing I am not so sure about is if it is allowed to use imaginary numbers in $r$, as this is counter-intuitive from its derivation, and I'm gonna confirm it with my math doctor.

Hope this helps.